# I am not able run the exe for python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  lables
  .
  .
```

When I use pyinstaller and make a file executable it is throwing error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "oracledb\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "oracledb\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thin/crypto.pyx", line 32, in init oracledb.thin_impl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
[23280] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Traceback.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

You need to install all the modules used by the python script if you want to generate the executable.

```
pip install cryptography
```

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (37.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cryptography) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography) (2.21)

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.1.2 -> 22.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: what is the command used ?

Comment: pip install cryptography

Comment: sorry the command to compile the executable

Comment: I need the command you used to create the .exe file (which is the compiled program) from the .py file

Comment: pyinstaller main.py

Comment: pyinstaller main.py

Comment: locate local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (get the full path) try pyinstaller --onefile -w --paths=(the full path)  main.py

Comment: remove the parenthesis in the path

Comment: What does : pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import cryptography -w --paths=the full path main.py give you ?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this run the command:

```
pip install cryptography
```

PS: If you type in terminal:

```
pip freeze
```

You can see all modules/libraries installed in your virtual enviroment.

Comment: PS C:\Users\7000023406\PycharmProjects\APP_REG> pip freeze
altgraph==0.17.2
bcrypt==3.2.2
cffi==1.15.1
cryptography==37.0.4
cx-Oracle==8.3.0
future==0.18.2
MouseInfo==0.1.3
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
oracledb==1.0.2
paramiko==2.11.0
pbkdf2==1.3
pefile==2022.5.30
protobuf==4.21.2
PyAutoGUI==0.9.53
pycparser==2.21
PyGetWindow==0.0.9
pyinstaller==5.2
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.8
PyMsgBox==1.0.9
PyMySQL==1.0.2
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyperclip==1.8.2
PyRect==0.2.0
PyScreeze==0.1.28
pytweening==1.0.4
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
six==1.16.0